# On reduction of variables in a system of differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given a system of linear differential equations $X' = A(t)X$, where $A(t)$ is an $n\times n$ matrix, if $k$ linearly independent solutions are known, how to reduce to the solution of a system of linear differential equations $Y' = B(t)Y$, where $B(t)$ is an $(n-k)\times(n-k)$ matrix? 
I saw the statement as a theorem in a book(but without proof), can anybody help me out?Thanks.

Comment: Is there a relation between both $x$ and $Y$ or $A$ and $B$?

Comment: Yes. The new system should come from a linear transformation of the old.

Comment: There is a known algorithm of doing this. But I want to know if there is a simple explanation from the viewpoint of linear transformation.